# C# - Reuse IPEndPoint Object

Tags: c#, optimization, network-programming, memory-efficient

As part of an educational project, I started to work on highly-optimized MMO game server in C#.

I try to avoid as much as I can from extra memory allocation, and I wanted to ask if it is possible
to reuse an [IPEndPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipendpoint?view=netcore-3.1) object without allocating memory.

I would expect something like this (the function I want is `IPEndPoint.DeepCopy`):

```
public void Send(IPEndPoint toIP, byte[] buffer, int numOfBytes)
    {
        // try aquire send event from free list
        SocketAsyncEventArgs e;
        bool successfullyTaken = this._writeEventArgsPool.TryTake(out e);

        // copy buffer
        // ....

        // set the outgoing IP
        IPEndPoint.DeepCopy(toIP, e.RemoteEndPoint);
        
        // send the packet
        //..
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: An IPEndPoint is a property of a socket class when the connection completes. The end point is disposed when the connection closes so it can't be reused.  And you can't change the endpoint when the connection is opened.  So you cannot reuse the endpoint.

Comment: @jdweng thats actually not true. Using UDP protocol and the RecieveMessageFromAsync will put the content inside SocketAsyncEventArgs object (in the RemoreEndPoint field), that won't be disposed.

Comment: The example posted in the link is TCP.  The SocketAysncEvent gets a socket and when the socket is disposed then the endpoint get disposed.  You are not saying anything different that what i said.

Comment: @jdweng you are wrong again, this object is used also in UDP, without returning socket, only the message in the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to avoid allocations from IPEndPoint for now. There's [a proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30797)! but it has not seen much progress. One can fiddle with the SocketAddress serialization using a custom EndPoint for specific usage as done in [No-gc-sockets](https://github.com/forestrf/No-gc-sockets)! but there's no guarantee that this strategy will work across .NET implementations. The MutableIPEndPoint in No-gc-sockets for example seems to work fine for .NETFramework 4.7.x but not .NETCore 3.x due to internal implementation details.